# Pagination in flutter bloc

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

Is it possible to use pagination in bloc pattern? 
I am getting the data from api after hitting only once. So I want to load items 10 after 10 upto 100 items on scroll without hitting api.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. If your initial call to the API fetch 100 items, then you can present them 10 at a time, with or without flutter bloc.

There are many examples already avalable here on SO. You can for example search for infinite scroll to get a whole bunch of different alternatives.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=flutter+infinite+scroll